# plot line between points pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot lines between two points and my points are defined in different columns.

```
#coordinates of the points
#point1(A[0],B[0])
#point2(C[0],D[0])
#line between point1 and point 2

#next line would be
#point3(A[1],B[1])
#point4(C[1],D[1])    
#line between point3 and point 4

plot_result:
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  0  4  7  1  5  1
1  2  5  8  3  3  1
2  3  4  9  5  6  1
3  4  5  4  7  9  4
4  6  5  2  1  2  7
5  1  4  3  0  4  7
```

i tried with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(0, len(plot_result.A), 1):
    plt.plot(plot_result.A[i]:plot_result.B[i], plot_result.C[i]:plot_result.D[i], 'ro-')

plt.show()
```

but it is a invalid syntax. I have no idea how to implement this

Comment: In matplotlib a line between two points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` is created via `plt.plot([x1,x2], [y1,y2])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two parameters of the method plot are x and y which can be single points or array-like objects. If you want to plot a line from the point (x1,y1) to the point (x2,y2) you have to do something like this:

```
for plot_result in plot_result.values: # if plot_results is a DataFrame
    x1 = row[0] # A[i]
    y1 = row[1] # B[i]
    x2 = row[2] # C[i]
    y2 = row[3] # D[i]
    plt.plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2]) # plot one line for every row in the DataFrame.
```